# angular 2 inputfield with autocomplete doesn't call change method when autocomplete option is selected

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, angular2-forms

I am building a child component in Angular 2 and need to be able to select a value from an autocomplete list. The list is a simple list of frequently used numbers (single digit), it will be used as a reminder for the user (also to make it easier in use as these values will be often needed). I get the correct list and I can select values but I need these values to trigger the (change) event in the input menu (or trigger this in the autocomplete itself). I managed to get it working by clicking on the option but not when you navigate with the keyboard and confirm with enter.

My component&html template:(snippet wont function as I pass data from parent)

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from "@angular/core";
import {FormControl} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'hourcomponent',
  templateUrl: './hour.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hour.component.css']
})

export class hourComponent {
  @Input() uur = "";
  @Input() type: boolean;
  @Input() edit: boolean;
  @Input() day: number;
  @Input() mostUsed: number[];
  @Output() Callback = new EventEmitter<number>();

  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  dagen = ["MA", "DI", "WO", "DO", "VR", "ZA", "ZO"];

  callback(uur: string){
    var tijd = parseInt(uur);
    this.Callback.emit(tijd);
  }
}
```

```html
<td>
  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="uur" placeholder="{{dagen[day]}}" [disabled]=edit (change)="callback(uur)" [mdAutocomplete]="auto">
  </md-input-container>

</td>
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let most of mostUsed" [value]="most" (click)="callback(most)" >
    {{most}}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```